# How to parse SOAP response in JAX-WS?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

How should i parse SOAP response? Do i have to write LogicalHandler (like here http://www.java-tips.org/java-ee-tips/java-api-for-xml-web-services/writing-a-handler-in-jax-ws.html) to get the payload of response and then use SAX to parse it or are there any other handy methods in JAX to do this?

I only need data from some xml tags in response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use any JAX-WS implementation (CXF, Axis2, Metro) you shouldn't really have to parse responses. You can generate JAXB annotated classes from the WSDL of the web service you want to access and have marshallers to bind the XML payload to generated java beans.

Comment: I created WS cient from WSDL. So i only have to find the right generated methods to access some fields within response?

Comment: Yes, you should have methods with the same name as your WSDL service operations. These methods should return objects that are bound to your response.

Comment: I only found generated methods that return one giant String for all WS operations (axis1 client on this wsdl: http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/DWMLgen/wsdl/ndfdXML.wsdl). I guess i will have to use substring or regex to get something out of this.